# I tried to install PR2 simulation on Indigo but i get the command like this --- E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-pr2-desktop

Tags: ros, pr2, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

output:

```
sudo apt-get install ros-indigo-pr2-desktopReading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.list.' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.list.' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.list.' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
E: Unable to locate package ros-indigo-pr2-desktop
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/245019/i-tried-to-install-pr2-simulation-on-indigo-but-i-get-the-command-like-this-----e:-unable-to-locate-package-ros-indigo-pr2-desktop----what-should-i-do?/) by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2016-10-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Edit: not sure what the current status is, but at least at the time of answering [Unable to locate package ros-indigo-pr2-desktop](http://answers.ros.org/question/231237) `pr2_desktop` was not being released any more.

Ignoring that, your ROS install has a problem. See below.

> ```
> N: Ignoring file 'ros-latest.list.' in directory '/etc/apt/sources.list.d/' as it has an invalid filename extension
> ```

I don't know whether the rest of your configuration is correct, but the error message is clear: `apt` is ignoring your `ros-latest.list.` because it does not have the file extension it is expecting.

Apt only loads files (in this case at least) with the extension `.list`. Your file has an extra dot (`.`) at the end: `.list.`.

Just remove that dot, and things should work a little better.

Suggestion:

```
sudo mv /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list. /etc/apt/sources.list.d/ros-latest.list
```

Then try `sudo apt-get update` again. <del>After that you can try to install the package</del> (that won't work, as the package hasn't / won't be released, but other packages should now work).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2016-10-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Abhinav Sonone](https://answers.ros.org/users/28155/abhinav-sonone/) on 2016-10-08**:
that worked just fine! thanks alot :)